# Spring / Jersey / Grizzly causing silent test failure in maven command-line, but succeeds in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, grizzly, jersey-1.0

We have a JUnit / Jersey integration test that is failing with "Connection Refused" when run from the command-line via Maven. However, when run from Eclipse the test passes. It seems that there is some error with the Grizzly container not starting, but I cannot find any error messages or log, it just fails silently. This is occurring while we are upgrading from Java 7 CentOS 6 environment to Java 8 CentOS 7 environment. Below is a simple test that reproduces this error:

```
public class CrobichaGrizzlyIntegrationTest extends JerseyTest {
    private WebResource webResource;
    private static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "xxx";
    byte[] bytes;
    byte[] expectedResponses;

    public CrobichaGrizzlyIntegrationTest() {
        super(
                new WebAppDescriptor.Builder(PACKAGE_NAME)
                        .clientConfig(
                                new DefaultClientConfig()).servletPath("/")
                        .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:app-config.xml")
                        .servletClass(SpringServlet.class)
                        .contextListenerClass(ContextLoaderListener.class)
                        .build()
        );
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        bytes = ReputationHelper.createReputationRequest().toByteArray();
        expectedResponses = ReputationHelper.createReputationResponse().toByteArray();
    }

    // 1. valid POST/GET(E2E) request
    @Test
    public void testPostRequestSuccess() throws Exception {
        webResource = resource().path("xyz").queryParam("query", "value");

        final byte[] response =
                webResource.type(HttpUtils.MIME_APPLICATION_PROTOBUF).accept(HttpUtils.MIME_APPLICATION_PROTOBUF)
                        .cookie(new Cookie("cookie", "abcd")).post(byte[].class, bytes);

        final ResponseList expectedResponseList = ResponseList.parseFrom(expectedResponses);
        final ResponseList responseList = ResponseList.parseFrom(response);

        Assert.assertEquals(expectedResponseList.getResponse(0), responseList.getResponse(0));
    }
}
```

Error report from maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="xxx.CrobichaGrizzlyIntegrationTest" time="0" tests="1" errors="1" skipped="0" failures="0">
  <properties>
    <property name="java.runtime.name" value="Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment"/>
    <property name="sun.boot.library.path" value="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/amd64"/>
    <property name="java.vm.version" value="25.45-b02"/>
    <property name="java.vm.vendor" value="Oracle Corporation"/>
    <property name="java.vendor.url" value="http://java.oracle.com/"/>
    <property name="path.separator" value=":"/>
    <property name="guice.disable.misplaced.annotation.check" value="true"/>
    <property name="java.vm.name" value="Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM"/>
    <property name="file.encoding.pkg" value="sun.io"/>
    <property name="user.country" value="US"/>
    <property name="sun.java.launcher" value="SUN_STANDARD"/>
    <property name="sun.os.patch.level" value="unknown"/>
    <property name="java.vm.specification.name" value="Java Virtual Machine Specification"/>
    <property name="user.dir" value="---removed---"/>
    <property name="java.runtime.version" value="1.8.0_45-b14"/>
    <property name="java.awt.graphicsenv" value="sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment"/>
    <property name="java.endorsed.dirs" value="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/endorsed"/>
    <property name="os.arch" value="amd64"/>
    <property name="java.io.tmpdir" value="/tmp"/>
    <property name="line.separator" value="&#10;"/>
    <property name="java.vm.specification.vendor" value="Oracle Corporation"/>
    <property name="os.name" value="Linux"/>
    <property name="classworlds.conf" value="/usr/share/maven/bin/m2.conf"/>
    <property name="sun.jnu.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="java.library.path" value="/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib"/>
    <property name="java.specification.name" value="Java Platform API Specification"/>
    <property name="java.class.version" value="52.0"/>
    <property name="sun.management.compiler" value="HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers"/>
    <property name="os.version" value="3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64"/>
    <property name="user.home" value="/home/chris_robichaud"/>
    <property name="user.timezone" value="America/New_York"/>
    <property name="java.awt.printerjob" value="sun.print.PSPrinterJob"/>
    <property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="java.specification.version" value="1.8"/>
    <property name="user.name" value="chris_robichaud"/>
    <property name="java.class.path" value="/usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds.jar"/>
    <property name="java.vm.specification.version" value="1.8"/>
    <property name="sun.arch.data.model" value="64"/>
    <property name="java.home" value="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre"/>
    <property name="sun.java.command" value="org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher integration-test -rf :project_name -X"/>
    <property name="java.specification.vendor" value="Oracle Corporation"/>
    <property name="user.language" value="en"/>
    <property name="awt.toolkit" value="sun.awt.X11.XToolkit"/>
    <property name="java.vm.info" value="mixed mode"/>
    <property name="java.version" value="1.8.0_45"/>
    <property name="java.ext.dirs" value="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext"/>
    <property name="sun.boot.class.path" value="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/classes"/>
    <property name="java.vendor" value="Oracle Corporation"/>
    <property name="maven.home" value="/usr/share/maven"/>
    <property name="file.separator" value="/"/>
    <property name="java.vendor.url.bug" value="http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/"/>
    <property name="sun.cpu.endian" value="little"/>
    <property name="sun.io.unicode.encoding" value="UnicodeLittle"/>
    <property name="sun.desktop" value="gnome"/>
    <property name="sun.cpu.isalist" value=""/>
  </properties>
  <testcase name="testPostRequestSuccess" classname="xxx.CrobichaGrizzlyIntegrationTest" time="0">
    <error message="java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused" type="com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException"><![CDATA[com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1282)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1257)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler$1$1.getOutputStream(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:238)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider.writeTo(ByteArrayProvider.java:95)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider.writeTo(ByteArrayProvider.java:59)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:300)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:217)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
    at xxx.CrobichaGrizzlyIntegrationTest.testPostRequestSuccess(CrobichaGrizzlyIntegrationTest.java:88)
]]></error>
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace and the logs

Comment: Added stack trace and error report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to add an answer in case anyone else runs into this issue: I spent some time cleaning up my maven pom files and it seems to have fixed it. Never did find the root cause.